# On Windows 7 restarting, Apache running produces an Exception (Error launching process)

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp

I tried to run Apache on Windows 7, but every time I turn off Windows and I run Apache server these errors occurs:

> EXCEPTION: Problem launching process c:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe

> EXCEPTION: Problem launching process "c:\xampp\apache\bin\mysqld.exe" --default-file="c:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini" --standalone

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: Hi Warteg, welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please also post the error as plain text in your message? This helps people to better read the text and copy out parts of it. Also your post is missing a real question. Me personally I prefer to respond to posts which have a clear question in it and maybe you can also describe what you have already done trying to solve your problem.

Comment: Are there any hints in the individual application logs for Apache or MySQL?